How to update parts of a theme in observable framework?
I feel silly for asking but I don't understand how to customize a theme in an observable framework data app. The documentation seems to suggest creating a theme from scratch, but all I really want to do is change the font. I figure I must first import the theme I want as the base (near-midnight) and then just override the font styling but the following seems to be missing all of the other styling included in the default theme (layout for example).
My style.css:
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@import url("observablehq:theme-near-midnight.css");

:root {
  --sans-serif: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: var(--sans-serif);
}


I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but not sure how to work this out.
Tried importing the theme from observablehq, asked ChatGPT (it got me closer than I was). Searched the forums here but didn't anything.
End result will be it looks and behaves just like the near-midnight theme out of the box, but with a sans-serif font.

I'm not familiar with observablehq. I'm not sure what exactly is not working. You're importing the Inter font and set the text as this font. So far, observablehq is not involved. Maybe the framework is actually overrides the font?

Hi @MoshFeu, Observable Framework is for building data-centric web apps. The documentation just has me a bit confused: https://observablehq.com/framework/themes
Maybe I just need to copy all of the source styles and dependencies and put them in a single stylesheet. Just seemed like there was a better way.

To related to your specific question, as far as I understand the issue isn’t related to the framework - the font is from Google and the style isn't targeting any framework class or other entities (e.g. body, h1 etc.). If the problem was that the framework style don't apply, then I'd investigate things about the framework, but the issue you mention is not that.

Ok, I just went through the documentation again and realized my mistake.
https://observablehq.com/framework/config#style explained it, I think I was confused when I first read this.
So the trick is in fact to import both the default stylesheet and the theme stylesheet.
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@import url("observablehq:default.css");
@import url("observablehq:theme-near-midnight.css");

:root {
  --sans-serif: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: var(--sans-serif);
}

